# Induction proof into wolframalpha not working

Tags: induction, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to write this into wolframalpha without luck. Anyone know how to check it in there?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as $$3^n>2^n$$ this is simpler to handle.